# Exception Handling and initialization

Tags: java, exception, initialization, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I'm working on pre-build EJB application. I'm using Sonar for code improvements. 
I'm seeing this type of code block in almost every try-catch situation:

```
String ex = null;
try{
   ex = demo();
}catch(Exception e){
   ex=null;
   throw new Exception("message",e);
}
```

I want to ask that, writing "ex=null" in catch block is good or not? Means sonar is seeing it as useless code.

One more thing, the JDK version used to develop is **JDK 6.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do it (ex=null). Variable ex will be uninitialized, when demo() throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside that this is very bad exception handling, no, you don't need to call `ex=null`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it. This is a bad exception handling approach.